# Comparing $ E(Y|X) $, $ E(Y|p(X)) $, $ E(Y|X, p(X)) $

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

Consider 2 random variables $Y,X$ and a function $p(X)$. I would like to understand the relation between these 3 conditional expectations
$$
E(Y|X)
$$
$$
E(Y|p(X))
$$
$$
E(Y|X, p(X))
$$

My intuition is that if we condition on $X=x$, we implicitly condition on $p(X)=p(x)$ too so that 
$$
E(Y|X=x, p(X)=\bar{p})=
\begin{cases}
E(Y|X=x) & \text{if $\bar{p}=p(x)$}\\
\text{Undefined } & \text{ otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore, 
$$
E(Y|X)=E(Y|X, p(X))
$$

On the other hand, 
$$
E(Y|p(X))\neq E(Y|X)
$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ denotes a Borel-measurable function then it is correct that: $$\mathbb E[Y\mid X]=\mathbb E[Y\mid p(X),X]$$

This because the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that makes $X$ measurable is the same as  the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that makes $X$ and $p(X)$ measurable (this on base of the fact that measurablity of $X$ implies measurablility of $p(X)$).

It is wrong to state that $\mathbb E[Y\mid p(X)]\neq\mathbb E[Y\mid X]$.

For instance it might be that $p$ is the identity function on $\mathbb R$, and in that situation it is not true.

There are also situation where it is true.

For instance if $X=Y$ and is not degenerate and $p$ is a constant function.